# How to listen to local state changes with React Apollo

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, apollo, react-apollo

I am creating a React app with Apollo Graphql and I am also using it to manage my local state.

In my code I have a component that is used to query my graphql server with some local @client fields and pass the data to its child components:

```js
function ProductDetails(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [subproducts, setSubproducts] = useState(new Array<Product>());

  const productQuery = useGetProductDetailsQuery({
    variables: {
      productId: Number(props.match.params.productId),
      companyId: Number(props.match.params.companyId),
    },
    onCompleted: data => {
      const result = flattenSubproductsConnection(data!.getProducts as ProductConnection);
      setSubproducts(result);
      console.log('Result', result);
    },
  });

  return (
    <Box display='flex' flexDirection='column'>
      {subproducts.map(subproduct => (
        <Choosable product={subproduct} key={subproduct.numericalId!} />
      ))}
    </Box>
  );
}
```

Each child component can fire a mutation that changes the overall state, for example:

```js
export default function QuantitySimple(props: Props) {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const [increaseQuantity] = useIncreaseChosenProductQuantityMutation({
    variables: { productId: props.product.id },
  });
  const onIncreaseQuantityClick = useCallback(() => {
    increaseQuantity();
  }, []);

  const [decreaseQuantity] = useDecreaseChosenProductQuantityMutation({
    variables: { productId: props.product.id },
  });
  const onDecreaseQuantityClick = useCallback(() => {
    decreaseQuantity();
  }, []);

  return (
    <ListItem>
      <Box display='flex' alignItems='center'>
        <span onClick={onDecreaseQuantityClick}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faMinusCircle} size='lg' />
        </span>
        <Typography className={classes.text}>{props.product.chosenQuantity}</Typography>
        <span onClick={onIncreaseQuantityClick}>
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPlusCircle} size='lg' />
        </span>
      </Box>
      <ListItemText className={classes.text} primary={props.product.name} />
      <ListItemText primary={getProductPrice(props.product)} />
    </ListItem>
  );
}
```

So, whenever I click on the plus or minus icons on the component above, I the local state of the application changes, but this change is not being reflected on the UI.

Please note that `props.product.chosenQuantity` is a local @client field on my Graphql query and it comes all the way from the parent component. Am I doing something wrong?

Should I create a specific @client query just to get this field on my child components?

I also tried to use the `watchQueries` from the Apollo client like so:

```js
  const apolloClient = useApolloClient();

  apolloClient
    .watchQuery({
      query: GetProductDetailsDocument,
      variables: {
        productId: Number(props.match.params.productId),
        companyId: Number(props.match.params.companyId),
      },
    })
    .subscribe(queryResult => {
      console.log('Query Result', queryResult);
      const result = flattenSubproductsConnection(queryResult.data
        .getProducts as ProductConnection);
      setSubproducts(result);
    });
```

But then this subscription is fired all the time, without any changes at all, so I guess I am also doing something wrong with it.

Could someone help me?